# Autosorting DataGrid by Date and List Index in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I am populating a List with objects that have a DateTime value. I want to display them in a DataGrid, with ItemsSource set as the List in this manner:

- All the elements should be sorted ascending by DateTime value.
- If there are multiple elements with the same DateTime value, I want them to be ordered  **ascending** by their index in the list.

I have created a sample app to illustrate the behaviours, using MVVM framework provided by Caliburn.Micro
The View:

```
 <StackPanel>
            <StackPanel.Resources>
                <CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding Files}" x:Key="filesView"  IsLiveSortingRequested="True" >
                    <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
                        <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="Date" Direction="Ascending"/>
                        <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="Index" Direction="Ascending"/>
                    </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
                </CollectionViewSource>
            </StackPanel.Resources>
            <DataGrid 
                IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" 
                IsReadOnly="True"   
                ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource filesView}}" 
                AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Index" Binding="{Binding Index}" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Text}" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Date" Binding="{Binding Date}" />
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
            <Button x:Name="Add">Add</Button>
        </StackPanel>
```

The ViewModel:

```
public class ShellViewModel : Screen
    {
        private BindableCollection<DataGridItem> _files = new BindableCollection<DataGridItem>();
        public BindableCollection<DataGridItem> Files
        {
            get { return _files; }
            set
            {
                _files = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Files);


            }
        }
        public ShellViewModel()
        {

        }
        public void Add()
        {
            int index = Files.Count; 
            Random random = new Random();
            const string chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
            string name = new string(Enumerable.Repeat(chars, 4).Select(s => s[random.Next(s.Length)]).ToArray());
            DateTime date  = DateTime.Today.AddDays(random.Next(2));

            DataGridItem dgi = new DataGridItem();
            dgi.Text = name;
            dgi.Date = date;
            dgi.Index = index;
            Files.Add(dgi);

        }
    }
    public class Item
    {
        public List<DataGridItem> DataGridItems { get; set; }
    }

    public class DataGridItem
    {
        public int Index { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    }
```

For now, I have managed to do what I want by adding an extra property to the object that is represented by the index and then binding the DataGrid to a CollectionViewSource which has two SortDescription (Date and Index).

Is there a simpler way to achieve my purpose, without the need of using an Index property?
I don't want to manually set a property of an element as the index of the List, having in mind that you can get the index of an element in a list using IndexOf method.

Without using the Index property that I have created, the elements with the same DateTime value would be ordered by index, but Descending. The latest element added would be the first in the top of the group of elements with the same DateTime.

Comment: How would you sort them by "their index" if they don't have an index...? If there is no `Index` property there is no concept of an index, is it? Or what you mean by index?

Comment: By index I mean the index in the List. Every element of a list has an index even though you don't add an Index property and maybe you can refer to its index inside the List. For example, you can bind in WPF directly to a List.Count and I thought that there is a similar way to get the Index of the element of a List.

Comment: No, an item doesn't have an index. It doesn't even know that a reference to it may have been added to a `List<T>`. The index within the list is not known to either the item itself nor the control.

Comment: Even though the Control is an ItemsControl? Wouldn't you be somehow to display the index for each element in the ItemsSource using pure XAML?

Comment: No. The ItemsControl doesn't expose any index that you can bind to.

Comment: Thanks! But is there any other way to sort them the way I have described?

Comment: No. You need to specify how the items should be sorted if you decide to sort the view.